# Azure LBS REST API

Tags: azure-maps

Found this REST endpoint in docs for Azure LBS service.
https://atlas.microsoft.com/timezone/byCoordinates/json?api-version=1.0&options=all&query=47.0,-122&subscription-key=

But it doesn't seem to be working. 
Can't seem to ping it also.

PS C:\Users\xyz> ping https://atlas.microsoft.com
Ping request could not find host https://atlas.microsoft.com. Please check the name and try again.
Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add your Azure Location Based Services subscription key to the end of that URL. I just appended my key to it and it worked fine. Documentation on how to create an account/key for this platform can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/location-based-services/how-to-manage-account-keys

Yes this service is supported, in fact, it is a new service that is in preview and will move out of preview soon.